# My Donut Will Not Bake

Tags: texturing, texture-baking

I am new to blender but I spent hours watching tutorials online on baking. I created myself a donut and textured it however, when I press A to select all, it only selects the icing which is a separate mesh from the donut itself. How do I bake the entire donut and not just the icing? PROBLEM: When I try to select the entire donut in edit mode, it only selects the icing.

Donut: 
[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgB4E.jpg

Blender:
[image]
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/atvsJ.jpg

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and use the tools from this site to upload images so that they appear as part of your question. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please correct me if I am wrong but, it looks like you have 2 objects and only have one of them selected. One being the doughnut, the second being the icing. In order to bake them you must first Join the 2 meshes together, making one object. Do this by selecting both objects in Object Mode. Shift + Right Mouse Button (provided you use default controls). Then with the mouse in the 3D viewport tap the spacebar to access the search function and type "Join". Select the first option. Both meshes are now one object. Then unwrap them. Once that is done, then you can bake the entire doughnut.

Comment: How do I unwrap the single object?

Comment: Proper unwrapping is more difficult to explain via text. I recommend this Youtube video that is provided by Andrew Price, he is very good at Blender education and well known in the Blender community. Watch the entire video, and you should have a good understanding of how to unwrap meshes. Not every model is the same, some more difficult than others, but the same principles apply. :) https://youtu.be/scPSP_U858k