# Baking Andrew Price's Donut in order to 3D Print

Tags: cycles-render-engine, baking, 3d-printing

Long story but I'll try to bullet point it to make it simpler:

- I have a fancy 3d Printer that can print 500,000 colors.  [See my question here for a photo example](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/155037/3d-printing-objs-with-material-from-blender-2-8?noredirect=1#comment263567_155037).
- In that question I brought up that I was having trouble UV unwrapping and baking objects, the texture wouldn't export and couldn't be viewed in my printer software.
- Well, with a simple cube I finally figured that out.
- I'd like to 3d print Andrew Price's donut.  Seen here:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rKPSB8tcXhQ
- Here's my version of it, check it out: 
  [image]
- There's multiple objects so I was having trouble figuring out how to bake them and export as one .obj (the file format my printer can use), until I read [this guy's question on here.](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/106841/my-donut-will-not-bake)  He's also trying to bake the donut.
- The suggestion to "join" them all into one object definitely helps with the unwrapping, but here's the problem:
- When I "join" them all into one object, the icing gets turned into one color like this: [image]

  - This same problem happens when I try to get it to my printer in other routes, i.e. exporting it as gltf, opening it in other software and having them export it as an obj.  I've actually been able to load it in my printer software like this:  [image]  but as you can see, icing is all one color (well, it lost it's color).

So my question is:  how can I either bake it, or convert it somehow into an .obj file that doesn't lose any textures or colors from the original donut.

Comment: That can't be one of your first models, can it?  It's really good.

Comment: Thanks.  Eh, it's only really good because I followed his tutorials pretty much to the letter.  His wood floor one, donut one, and some other guy's tutorial on lighting.  If you asked me to make anything form scratch it'd be much worse.

Comment: Still, you're off to a good start.  I like the dougnut cake material.  I don't know anything about 3d printing so I can't help you there, I just wanted to comment on the image. :)